# any solution to make pycharm work in windows 7 32-bit

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I am a beginner in Python. I have installed the latest version of python -3.8.3 in my system. Now to have the editor to start working on python, i tried to install pycharm community edition-free-open source from the official site.While running it, I get the message as 'The installation has JetBrains Runtime 11 which does not support Microsoft Windows version 7 32-bit.
 Is there any other solution or alternative or IDE for python of windows 7 32-bit to work on?

Comment: [Support for Windows 7 has ended](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, other than using an older version of PyCharm.